# Change the format of a date and time

Tags: python, date, time

Below I have the format of a date and time I receive and I want to change it to the following format (in python). I essentially want to add a new column in my dataframe that has the date in the second format.

**Received format**: 2019-11-20T01:04:18+01:00

**Format wanted**: 20-11-19 1:04

If anyone knows the code to convert it, it would be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried so far and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You simply use **strftime()** and **strptime()**.
Please refer to documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

below thanks

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-11-20T01:04:18', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
print d.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
```

and to get week number

```
print d.isocalendar()[1]
```

Comment: It works thank you very much. Do you by any chance know how to add the week number in a different column? For example, that date is within week 47.

Comment: `print d.isocalendar()[1]` ammended above to show